# Proper ideal of Boolean ring

Tags: abstract-algebra, boolean-algebra

Let M be proper ideal of Boolean ring R.
Which of the following is/are true?
1.$R/M$  is Boolean ring.
2.$R/M$ $\cong$ $Z_2$  if and only if M is maximal ideal.

Comment: Both of these questions solve themselves almost immediately. Where exactly are you stuck?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hints:

1) $(x+M)(x+M)=$?

2) $R/M$ is certainly a field. An element of a field satisfying $a^2=a$ is a root of the polynomial $x^2-x$. With 1), what does this say about the field?